# set user id as the current user in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, jfactory, account-password

I have a userId - `$uid`.

I wanted to make this user as logged in to the s/m in joomla.

I've tried this -

```
$currentUser = new JUser($uid);

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$credentials = array();
$credentials['username'] = $currentUser->username;
$credentials['password'] = $currentUser->password; //this is the hashed password

//perform the login action
$mainframe->login($credentials);

$newuser = JFactory::getUser(); //this doesn't get updated to the new user ($uid) details
```

How can I make the user as the current user by using the uid itself?

**Update**: I just found that user can be loaded with JUser::load()

Trial 2-

```
$user = JUser::getInstance($uid);
$user->load($uid); //this should load the new user.

$newuser = JFactory::getUser(); //still i get the anonymous details here 
            //($newuser->id = 0)
```

As there is `wp_set_current_user($uid);` for wordpress `user_load_by_name()` in drupal, is there any similar function for joomla ? Please help.!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Note - If I add the hardcoded password to $credentials['password'], it works. But I can't hardcode it, can i get the unhashed passwd from the hashed one?

Comment: It is a little bit vague what you are trying to accomplish. Can you explain your workflow a little bit better? Are you trying to have a default logged in use? Do your users log in to your site using a login form? Can you tell us what "s/m" is?

Comment: cross-posted on `stackoverflow.com` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554014/set-user-id-as-the-current-user-in-joomla

Comment: @TerryCarter the users are not logging from the login form, it is like I'm calling a rest api which has username and password. Using this I need to make this user as the current user so that it gets the required permissions!

Comment: @jitendrapurohit - So you want to update the ID of a currently logged in user? In which case, you'll need to update the ID in the database for that specific user.

Comment: @Lodder I don't want to update the id. Just wanted to make this user as a logged in user

Comment: Pass the username and password, form token to the com_users login controller then and let Joomla "login" the user for you. Using this method you will essentially be logging in the user without actually filling out a form.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075335/how-to-log-into-joomla-through-an-external-script

It is almost a duplicate of yours, it just needs to be updated to use JInput instead of JRequest

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this by using a core plugin...

```
//Will obtain user object - what the question author needed.
$user = JFactory::getUser($uid);

//Will authorize you as this user.
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('user');
$options = array();
$options['action'] = 'core.login.site';
$response->username = $user->username;
$result = $app->triggerEvent('onUserLogin', array((array)$response, $options));
```

Comment: Not sure if you can really login user this way, but I believe that first line of code is the answer that was issued. You might need to create custom plugin to login user without password.

Comment: Sure you can login with this, I have tested

Answer (score 1):

This may no have been available back then, but now I use two ways of loading users in Joomla.

**Method 1: Load any user as an instance of the User class**

Loading a user this way will simply store it in the variable and you can then use it for other things. This does not affect the current session and cannot make you login as a user.

```
<?php
$foo = JFactory::getUser(1234)
```

**Method 2: Load any user as currently logged in user**

```
<?php
JFactory::getUser()->load(1234)
```

After issuing this command, Joomla with see user 1234 as logged in. In fact, any subsequent call to `JFactory::getUser()` will return an instance of the `User` class for user id `1234`

**Edit**: If you are using this in a loop, it will help if you force Joomla to logout first by doing this ...

```
<?php
// First, logout ...
Factory::getApplication()->logout()
// ... then load the account.
JFactory::getUser()->load(1234)
```

I have seen a case where the loop kept remembering the first loaded item. It's probably due to a race condition somewhere in Joomla.